# List of dictionaries - Find count of values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

I am having difficulty to implement this logic.

Here is the input, list of dictionaries

```
list = [ 
    {"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc1", "agentname": "abcagent1", "env": "dev"},
    {"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc1", "agentname": "abcagent2", "env": "uat"},
    {"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc1", "agentname": "abcagent3", "env": "prod"},
    {"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc2", "agentname": "abcagent4", "env": "dev"},
    {"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc2", "agentname": "abcagent5", "env": "prod"},
    {"mne": "XYZ", "appname": "asf1", "agentname": "asfagent1", "env": "dev"},
    {"mne": "XYZ", "appname": "asf2", "agentname": "asfagent2", "env": "prod"},
]
```

Here is the output, I am looking for:

```
[
    {"mne": "ABC", "non_prod_app_count": 2, "prod_app_count": 2, "non_prod_agent_count": 3, "prod_agent_count": 2},
    {"mne": "XYZ", "non_prod_app_count": 1, "prod_app_count": 1, "non_prod_agent_count": 1, "prod_agent_count": 1}
]
```

Explanation:

```
non_prod (dev, uat)
prod (prod)
```

For the first dictionary in the output, here is the explanation.

```
non_prod_app_count = 2 (abc1, abc2)
prod_app_count = 2 (abc1, abc2)
non_prod_agent_count = 3 (abcagent1, abcagent2, abcagent4)
prod_agent_count = 2 (abcagent3, abcagent5)
```

Comment: Hey there! What have you tried?

Comment: I tired using Counter function.
**bold** `c = Counter()
for item in list:
   c[item["mne"] item["appname"], item["env"] ] += 1`


This gives output, but not the way, i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    {"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc1", "agentname": "abcagent1", "env": "dev"},
    {"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc1", "agentname": "abcagent2", "env": "uat"},
    {"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc1", "agentname": "abcagent3", "env": "prod"},
    {"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc2", "agentname": "abcagent4", "env": "dev"},
    {"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc2", "agentname": "abcagent5", "env": "prod"},
    {"mne": "XYZ", "appname": "asf1", "agentname": "asfagent1", "env": "dev"},
    {"mne": "XYZ", "appname": "asf2", "agentname": "asfagent2", "env": "prod"},
]

mne = {}
for d in lst:
    mne.setdefault(d["mne"], []).append(d)

out = []
for k, v in mne.items():

    env = {}
    for d in v:
        env.setdefault(d["env"], []).append(d)

    non_prod_app_count = set(
        i["appname"] for k, v in env.items() for i in v if k != "prod"
    )

    prod_app_count = set(v["appname"] for v in env["prod"])

    non_prod_agent_count = set(
        i["agentname"] for k, v in env.items() for i in v if k != "prod"
    )

    prod_agent_count = set(v["agentname"] for v in env["prod"])

    out.append(
        dict(
            mne=k,
            non_prod_app_count=len(non_prod_app_count),
            prod_app_count=len(prod_app_count),
            non_prod_agent_count=len(non_prod_agent_count),
            prod_agent_count=len(prod_agent_count),
        )
    )

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "mne": "ABC",
        "non_prod_app_count": 2,
        "prod_app_count": 2,
        "non_prod_agent_count": 3,
        "prod_agent_count": 2,
    },
    {
        "mne": "XYZ",
        "non_prod_app_count": 1,
        "prod_app_count": 1,
        "non_prod_agent_count": 1,
        "prod_agent_count": 1,
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use 'list' as your variable name.
Pandas is a tool that can help here. Its bulky but should get the job done.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [ 
{"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc1", "agentname": "abcagent1", "env": "dev"},
{"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc1", "agentname": "abcagent2", "env": "uat"},
{"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc1", "agentname": "abcagent3", "env": "prod"},
{"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc2", "agentname": "abcagent4", "env": "dev"},
{"mne": "ABC", "appname": "abc2", "agentname": "abcagent5", "env": "prod"},
{"mne": "XYZ", "appname": "asf1", "agentname": "asfagent1", "env": "dev"},
{"mne": "XYZ", "appname": "asf2", "agentname": "asfagent2", "env": "prod"},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
rows = []
for mne in df.mne.unique():
    tmp_df = df[df['mne']==mne]
    rows.append({
        'mne':mne,
        'non_prod_app_count': len(tmp_df[tmp_df['env']!= 'prod']['appname'].unique()),
        'prod_app_count':len(tmp_df[tmp_df['env']=='prod']['appname'].unique()),
        'non_prod_agent_count':len(tmp_df[tmp_df['env'].isin(['uat','dev'])]['agentname'].unique()),
        'prod_agent_count':len(tmp_df[tmp_df['env']=='prod']['agentname'].unique()),
    })

print(rows)
```

output:

```
[{'mne': 'ABC',
  'non_prod_app_count': 2,
  'prod_app_count': 2,
  'non_prod_agent_count': 3,
  'prod_agent_count': 2},
 {'mne': 'XYZ',
  'non_prod_app_count': 1,
  'prod_app_count': 1,
  'non_prod_agent_count': 1,
  'prod_agent_count': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you iterate the list of dictionaries and create a corresponding dictionary to store the different apps and agents.
Then, you iterate the entries and put the different names into their corresponding list.
Last, you count the length of the lists you've created

```
apps = {}

for l in list:
  app = l["mne"]
  if app not in apps.keys():
    apps[app] = {"mne": l["mne"],
                "non_prod_app": [], 
                "prod_app": [], 
                "non_prod_agent": [], 
                "prod_agent": []}
for l in list:
  app = l["mne"]
  if l["env"] == "prod":
    if l["appname"] not in apps[app]["prod_app"]:
        apps[app]["prod_app"].append(l["appname"])
    if l["agentname"] not in apps[app]["prod_agent"]:
        apps[app]["prod_agent"].append(l["agentname"])
  else:
    if l["appname"] not in apps[app]["non_prod_app"]:
        apps[app]["non_prod_app"].append(l["appname"])
    if l["agentname"] not in apps[app]["non_prod_agent"]:
        apps[app]["non_prod_agent"].append(l["agentname"])

returnList = []     
for l in apps.values():
    returnList.append({"mne": l["mne"],
                "non_prod_app": len(l["non_prod_app"]), 
                "prod_app": len(l["prod_app"]), 
                "non_prod_agent": len(l["non_prod_agent"]), 
                "prod_agent": len(l["prod_agent"])})
```